# MFMessageComposeViewController not returning to application after send message ios9

Tags: ios, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Previously on iOS7, I have tested my SMS module and it worked nicely. After updating the iOS version, I noticed that the SMS module have some problems.

In my .h file

```
#import <MessageUI/MFMessageComposeViewController.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

In my .m file

```
- (void)sendSMS:(NSString *)bodyOfMessage recipientList:(NSArray *)recipients
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = bodyOfMessage;
        controller.recipients = recipients;
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    if (result == MessageComposeResultCancelled){
        NSLog(@"Message cancelled");
    }
    else if (result == MessageComposeResultSent){
        NSLog(@"Message sent");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Message failed");
    }
}
```

After I press send, in the log have show "Message sent" but the view is still at the message screen. I have no idea why it will not go back to my application.

Need help to find the problem to why it will not go back to my application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dismiss your controller in your did finish delegate messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not dismissing the `mailcomposer` after it is presented. You will have to dismiss the presented `MFMessageComposeViewController` in the following method:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
         didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error 
{
    if (result == MessageComposeResultCancelled){
        NSLog(@"Message cancelled");
    }
    else if (result == MessageComposeResultSent){
        NSLog(@"Message sent");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Message failed");
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; //<---- This line
}
```

Moreover, `- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated` is deprecated since iOS 6. Use `- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion` instead like this:

```
[self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
```